# Computing the principal components using the given variance covariance matrix

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, eigenvalues

I have been given the following variance covariance matrix and I am required to compute the principal components of this matrix.

$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  0.5&  0.5& 0.5\\ 
 0.5& 1 & 0.5 & 0.5\\ 
0.5 &  0.5&1  & 0.5\\ 
 0.5 &  0.5&  0.5& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I know how to compute the components. We just need to first evaluate the characteristics roots and then corresponding to that we can compute the characteristic vector. I can do that in a lower dimension matrix easily by hand and even this one we can do with python or r but suppose I don't have access to the calculator and I want to compute the characteristic roots by hand of this 4 by 4 matrix. Now, My question is that can we apply some sort of matrix theory to make this matrix easy to deal with and hence easy to compute the characteristics roots. Here, I do realize that I cannot apply transformation to make some entries zero as characteristic roots are not invariant under elementary transformations.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Let $J=\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^T$ be the matrix (of size $n\times n$) where all components are 1 and $\mathbf{1}$ is the column vector of only 1's. Then we have $\Sigma = \rho J + (1-\rho) I$.  By manipulating $\Sigma$  in this form you can solve by hand!